# How to disable cross-site ajax policies in firefox?

Tags: ajax, cross-site

I need a way to request any site using Ajax. I mean ANY site, I don't want to have to use the workarounds that firefox offers that only apply to someone who's making page requests from the same domain. Is there ANY way to let this happen? I want this to occur as a local file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Downgrade your Firefox to under version 3
2. Try http://dirolf.com/2007/06/enabling-cross-domain-ajax-in-firefox.html

Firefox 3 note
Versions of Firefox prior to Firefox 3 allowed you to set the preference capability.policy..XMLHttpRequest.open to allAccess to give specific sites cross-site access. This is no longer supported.

BTW, you can also save your web application(.html) as .hta, HTA application is allow cross site scripting.

Comment: Thanks! Does the HTA file still work for FF4? I'm using Chrome now because of the --disable-security switch, which is more than simple enough.

Comment: HTA is desktop application. support Windows only. nothing to do with other browser. gave this suggestion just in case you may want to do something on you local computer only. =)